# how to change jtabbed pane selected tab color without affecting other Jtabbed panes in project

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtabbedpane

I am trying to change selected tab color in Jtabbed pane. I have used UIManager to change this. But when i go to other tabbed panes in my project the color of those selected panes are also affected because of this. Can you help me in resolving this?

Manoj Kumar N

Comment: Have you re-set your UIManager look and feel ? If you have changed it once and then not changed it back the program will automatically use this.

Comment: Can you help me in resolving this? I can't see where, how ..., for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE / MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Hi Nathan, How do i reset the UI manager values. Should i reset during call of another tabset?